# Non-Jew Allowed in the Sukkah

Tags: sources-mekorot, gentiles, sukkah

I heard in a class that there is either an prohibition or at least an inyan not to have a non-Jew in the sukkah.

What is the source for this?

Comment: https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/is-it-permissible-to-have-a-goy-in-a-sukkah

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.8b.4

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=9UM9AAAAcAAJ&lpg=RA6-PA32&ots=eKBQ91jfF-&dq=%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%95%D7%98%20%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%A7%D7%97%20%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93&pg=RA6-PA34#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Zohar in Emor. I saw it brought in the sefer Bad Kodesh (Rav Berel Povarsky) (Sukkos). That he learns the Zohar is excluding non-jews from the mitzva of Sukka. He happens to learn that it just means they don't get a mitzva if they sit in a sukka. But some understand the zohar that they shouldn't be in a sukka.
He doesn't qoute exact place where it is, so here's a picture of it.
[image]

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.3.103a.10?vhe=New_Torat_Emet_Zohar&lang=he

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.14.16

Comment: Rather surprising because the gemoro says that hashem will be giving them the mitsva of succa and then bring the rain down and they will get angry about it. In avoda zoro. It just says they will come for succos not that they will be in succos.  @DoubleAA

Comment: @Shlomy For some reason the picture from Bad Kodesh didn't show up in your post

Comment: @Dovmo I dont know.. for me it shows up. However the first comment is a link to that zohar.